# Question about polynomial quotient ring F[x]/(ax-b)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $F$ be a field. Fix elements $a \in F^{\times}$ and $b \in F$. Prove that the quotient ring $F[X]/(aX − b)$ is isomorphic to F.

So, I am thinking to use the first isomorphism theorem, and try to find some homomorphism $\phi: F[x] \rightarrow F$ that would have the kernel be equal to $Ax - b$. Then this would imply that $F$ is isomorphic to $F[X]/(aX − b)$. But I simply can't conceptualize such a homomorphism.

Is the logic flawed? If not, any hints about what sort of homomorphism $\phi$ would be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the homomorphism $\phi:F\left[x\right]\to F$ defined by $\phi\left(f\right)=f\left(ba^{-1}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homomorphism $\phi:F\left[x\right]\to F$ defined by $\phi\left(f\right)=f\left(ba^{-1}\right)$. This homomorphism is called "evaluation at $ba^{-1}$". It is not too hard to prove this is a homomorphism.  Now note that the kernel must be $\left(aX-b\right)$ for if a polynomial has $ba^{-1}$ as a root, then it must be some multiple of $aX-b$ .
Now prove that this map $\phi$ is surjective.